# Does sufism belongs to Islam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, sufism

Is sufism  a part of islam?  Or is it an adaption of any other religious practice.  I've read that sufism is emerged from the mixing up of hinduism with islam.   Praising prophet or any members of the prophet family through songs called khawali is anti islamic.

Comment: Absolutely its a part of Islam, and khawali doesn't denote sofism at all and indeed playing music in khawali is haram across all the though of schools

Comment: It would nice if you quoted a source for your claim: " I've read that sufism is emerged from the mixing up of hinduism with islam"

Answer (score 3):

Sufism is the practice of Tasawuff. It's focused on the practice of Tazkiya/Ihsan and the remembrance of Allah. There is no doubt that Tazkiya/Ihsan is a core part of Islam. Refer to the Gabriel Hadith where it is explicitly stated. And refer to the Prophet's (PBUH) Sunnah where he demonstrates this over and over.

Is there Bid'ah/Innovation in some Sufi literature and practice? Absolutely. But be wary that this goes for just about every approach out there, whether it's Salafi or Deobandi, etc. There is extremist and innovative literature/practice in every approach.

Refer also to the stance of Sufism in Islamic history. The first centuries, Sufism was regarded as the highest station, it is only later throughout the centuries where obvious innovation and extremism arises in the Sufi approach.

In short, yes, Sufism is part of Islam. Just be wary of the innovations that have seeped into some of it. Just as you should be wary of any approach out there. And give Sufism it's fair share of a just approach, just as you give good judgment of any Sunni approach out there that is based on the Quran and Sunnah.

I hope that makes sense, even though your question targets a fairly large topic and study.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: For the most part this is true, especially the part about any approach to or "school" of Islam can be susceptible to ideologies that stray from Islam. Two issues are left unaddressed. One you briefly touched on, where Sufi simply meant a "higher" and more "inner" effort  in Islam to attain the acceptance of Allah, and this involved a greater degree of humility as exemplified by community service and greater time and devotion spent in salat and thikr. But it seems to have morphed to "new age" and cult-like versions, often a leader to blindly follow, abandoning salat and mainstream practices.